# How do I configure nginx correctly to work with my Sinatra app running on thin?

Tags: nginx, sinatra, thin

I have a Sinatra app (`app.rb`) that resides within within `/var/www/example`. My setup is nginx, thin, and sinatra.

I have both nginx and thin up and running but when I navigate to my site, I get a 404 from nginx. I assume that the server block config is wrong. I've tried pointing root to `/var/www/example/` instead of `public` but that makes no difference. I don't think the request makes it as far as the sinatra app.

What am I doing wrong?

Server block:

```sh
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

config.ru within `/var/www/example` directory:

```
require File.expand_path('../app.rb', __FILE__)
run Sinatra::Application
```

config.yml within `/var/www/example` directory:

```yaml
---
 environment: production
 chdir: /var/www/example
 address: 127.0.0.1
 user: root
 group: root
 port: 4567
 pid: /var/www/example/pids/thin.pid
 rackup: /var/www/example/config.ru
 log: /var/www/example/logs/thin.log
 max_conns: 1024
 timeout: 30
 max_persistent_conns: 512
 daemonize: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell nginx to proxy requests to your Sinatra application. The minimum required to accomplish that is to specify a `proxy_pass` directive in the `location` block like this:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4567;
}
```

The [Nginx Reverse Proxy docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) have more information on other proxy settings you might want to include.